# What does npm mean by "optimal"?

Tags: npm

npm's documentation, [Getting started/Finding and Selecting Packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/searching-for-packages), says,

> To help you decide the best ones to explore, each package has been ranked according to four criteria using the npms analyzer:
>
> - Optimal
> - Popularity
> - Quality
> - Maintenance
>
> **Popularity** indicates how many times the package has been downloaded. This is a good indicator of packages that others have found to be especially useful, but not foolproof.
>
> **Quality** includes considerations such as the presence of a readme file, stability, tests, up-to-date dependencies, custom website, and code complexity.
>
> **Maintenance** ranks packages according to the attention given by developers. Packages that are maintained more frequently are more likely to work well with the current or upcoming versions of npm, for example.
>
> **Optimal** combines the three other criteria in a meaningful way.

What does "optimal" mean, i.e. what is the "meaningful way" in which it combines the three other criteria?

Or is that a bit secret (like Google's algorithm is, for deciding what search results to return)?

Comment: I can't imagine why someone thinks this is opinion-based: I'm asking whether someone knows what npm's algorithm is, for calculating "optimal" from the other three criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this [article](https://itnext.io/increasing-an-npm-packages-search-score-fb557f859300) it goes like this:

quality: 0.3, maintenance: 0.35 and popularity: 0.35

Answer (score 1):

It's calculated by npms as documented at https://api-docs.npms.io/ which says,

> - score-effect:14: Set the effect that package scores have for the final search score, defaults to 15.3
> - quality-weight:1: Set the weight that quality has for the each package score, defaults to 1.95
> - popularity-weight:1: Set the weight that popularity has for the each package score, defaults to 3.3
> - maintenance-weight:1: Set the weight that the quality has for the each package score, defaults to 2.05